# Flutter _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>?>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

This is the flutter code that I wrote 2 years ago. But I couldn't make any sense of why it has stopped working now.

How do I fix this exception.

```
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  const Quiz({
    super.key,
    required this.questions,
    required this.answerQuestion,
    required this.questionIndex,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>?>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(
              () => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer!['text'] as String);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the GitHub: https://github.com/Ankitkj1999/gfg_quiz/blob/master/lib/quiz.dart

Comment: could you include your print("data = ${questions[questionIndex]}") result?

Comment: You do know that Dart has null safety now? Two years ago it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>?>)
```

to this:

```
...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>?>?)
```

this happened because `questions[questionIndex]['answers']` is `null` and can't cast `null` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>?>`.

Comment: I had to do this to solve other exceptions. Now it doesn't show any error but the widget is not getting rendered in the screen.                                                                                                   ...?(questions[questionIndex]['answers']
                as List<Map<String, dynamic>?>?)
            ?.map((answer) {
          return Answer(
              () => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer!['text'] as String);
        }).toList()

Comment: could you include your print("data = ${questions[questionIndex]}") result? I think the data you looking for is empty and that is why you widget doesn't show up.

Comment: yes it is null, but we have initialized question in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I cloned your repo from GitHub, replaced **quiz.dart** with your code from the topic. There are things that must be done since some widgets are outdated:

1. Change **RaisedButton** to **ElevatedButton** (with the removal of **color** and **textColor** properties)
2. Change **FlatButton** to **TextButton** (with the removal of **textColor** property)

Other changes to **pubspec.yaml**:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.4 <3.0.0"
```

instead of sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

in result.dart change **Function** to **VoidCallback**:

```
  final VoidCallback resetHandler;
```

in answers.dart change **Function** to **VoidCallback**:

```
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;
```

And now, the code you provided here executed normally.